# SQL Where String Contains numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database that contains username with numbers in and some usernames where they don't have numbers. I want to make changes only to the users that have numbers in their username. How can I do this in SQL Server 2008?

I have tried the LIKE (0-9) which still changed all accounts.

Any suggestions would be good.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 4):

If you only want digits in the name:

```
where username not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: Or simply where username like '%[0-9]%'

Comment: @Sagar . . . That would return user names that contain at least one digit.

Comment: oh he means username with all numbers, then in that case can we use ISNUMERIC(Username)=1 ?

Comment: @Sagar . . . That would allow decimal points, leading hyphens, and the letter "e".